# Evaluating $\sum_{j\geqslant1}\sum_{k\geqslant1}(-1)^{k+j}\frac{(2k-1)+i(2j-1)}{((2k-1)^{2}+(2j-1)^{2})^{3/2}}.$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

After a test I've taken, I considered an infinite grid of eletric charges and wondered the resultant force at the origin. The origin has a charge $+1$ and every gaussian integer $a+bi$ in the first quadrant (only) with odd coefficients has charges too: $+1$ if $a+b\equiv0\pmod4$ and $-1$ if $a+b\equiv2\pmod4$. Every number $z$ applies a force of modulus $1/|z|^2$ at the origin. Working things out, I found the total force at the origin to be $$\sum_{j\geqslant1}\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+j}\left(\left(2k-1\right)+i\left(2j-1\right)\right)}{\left(\left(2k-1\right)^{2}+\left(2j-1\right)^{2}\right)^{3/2}}.$$

I don't have access to Mathematica/Maple nor have studied convergence/divergence tests thoroughly. Does it converge? If yes, does it have a nice closed form?

Comment: Mathematica says approximately $.0337201(1+i)$

Comment: The sum looks slightly suspicious; are you sure you wanted to have $(2k-1)$ rather than $(2k+1)$ (and likewise for $j$) in it? (alternatively; did you really want to start at $k=0$ rather than $k=1$?)

Comment: @PeterKošinár No, thanks. I'll edit it.

Comment: I understand that $\large{\rm i} = \sqrt{\,-1\,}\,$. Is't right ?.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: There are some methods that could be related to your problem ---> http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/~jb616/Preprints/Papers/Back%20Burner%20I/Salt/rec-madelung1.pdf

Comment: @FelixMarin great, so we are looking for a two-dimensional analog of the Madelung constant. This is important, and maybe there is a closed form for this simpler sum.

Comment: Is it _physically_ obvious in some way that the sum should converge?

Comment: @HandeBruijn I don't think convergence/divergence is obvious in any way here, unless there is something really easy I overlooked.

Comment: @TimRatigan Tyler Clark claims the sum diverges. Are you sure your calculation is correct? Although I edited the sum, it shouldn't diverge suddenly.

Comment: The sum is conditionally convergent, hence reindexing is dangerous due to the Riemann-Dini theorem.

Comment: The contribute to the force in the origin given by the points on $\max(\Im(z),\Re(z))=k$ is $O(1/k^2)$, hence if we sum "on annuli" we get a finite force, but if we choose a different detour we can make the force be any real number, since the force exerted by the positive (or negative) charges is not finite.

Comment: The issue here is that the double sum is not well-defined, we must choose a "path of summation" in order that the double sum is well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you type

> sum from j=1 to infinity of sum from k=1 to infinity of [(-1)^(k+j)((2k-1)+i*(2j-1))]/[((2k-1)^2+(2j-1)^2)^(3/2)]

into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20j=1%20to%20infinity%20of%20sum%20from%20k=1%20to%20infinity%20of%20%5B%28-1%29%5E%28k%2bj%29%28%282k%2b1%29%2bi%2a%282j%2b1%29%29%5D/%5B%28%282k%2b1%29%5E2%2b%282j%2b1%29%5E2%29%5E%283/2%29%5D), you get that the sum does not converge by the limit test. (Check it and make sure I haven't typed it in there wrong.) Wolfram Alpha is a free tool that can do nice calculations like this for you.

Comment: I am really confused now. In the original format of the sum, Mathematica said it was finite. Now, after a reindexing, Wolfram says it diverges.

Comment: I think Wolfram is wrong. I posted an answer proving (I think) convergence. I'd like you to see it and give me some feedback, e.g. check errors in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my justification of why this sum should converge: picking up the first sum and calling $2j-1=a$, we have $$(-1)^j\left(\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac{(-1)^k(2k-1)}{((2k-1)^2+a^2)^{3/2}}+ia\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{(-1)^k}{((2k-1)^2+a^2)^{3/2}}\right)\\\color{Red}{\leqslant_\star}(-1)^j\left(\frac{1}{2^{3/2}a^{3/2}}\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-1)^{1/2}}+\frac{ia}{2^{3/2}a^{3/2}}\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k-1)^{3/2}}\right)\tag{$\color{Red}{\text{AM-GM}}$}\\=(-1)^j\left(\frac{R+iaS}{2^{3/2}a^{3/2}}\right).$$ $R$ and $S$ both converge by the alternating series test. Now, let's put them in the second sum: $$\text{Original sum}\leqslant_\star\frac{1}{2^{3/2}}\left(R\sum_{j\geqslant1}\frac{(-1)^j}{(2j-1)^{3/2}}+iS\sum_{j\geqslant1}\frac{(-1)^j}{(2j-1)^{1/2}}\right)=\frac{RS}{2^{3/2}}\left(1+i\right).$$

Therefore, the sum converges. I abused the notation using order and complex numbers together, but it can be easily fixed by separating real and imaginary parts. We can see this as $a+bi\leqslant_\star c+ id\iff a\leqslant_\star c \,\text{and}\, b\leqslant_\star d$.